# script not working when on reboot, but when I power off/on it's working fine

Tags: pi-3, networking, pi-2

I wrote a script which is scheduled for a cron job at reboot.
This script changes the wlan1 from Managed to Monitor mode.

but when I reboot the pi, this script doesn't work and writes the error message `Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) : SET failed on device wlan1 ; Operation not supported`

But when I power off and on, this scripts executes successfully and changes mode from Managed to Monitor.

this is my script:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
currentDate=date
echo 'Going to change the mode of wlan1 at ${currentDate}'
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
    if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then
        sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
        echo 'Wlan1 mode changed to monitor';
    else
        echo 'There is some error occurred while changing the mode';
    fi
else
    echo 'Interface could not go down';
fi
```

My script is scheduled is like : `@reboot sudo /var/www/html/RaspiGUI/script/ModeChange-wlan1.sh`

any ideas?

Comment: What script, what error message, what, what?

Comment: My script is scheduled is like :
@reboot sudo /var/www/html/RaspiGUI/script/ModeChange-wlan1.sh

This script executes three commands
sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor
sudo ifconfig wlan1 up

And getting below error message:

Error for wireless request "Set Mode" (8B06) :
    SET failed on device wlan1 ; Operation not supported.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your comments there! And what script, please add the content!

Comment: My script is :

pi@ShopR360:~ $ sudo cat /var/www/html/RaspiGUI/script/ModeChange-wlan1.sh
#!/bin/bash

currentDate=`date`;
echo 'Going to change the mode of wlan1 at ${currentDate}'

sudo ifconfig wlan1 down
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then

sudo iwconfig wlan1 mode monitor

        if [[ $? -eq 0 ]];then

        sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
        echo 'Wlan1 mode changed to monitor';

        else

        echo 'There is some error occurred while changing the mode';

        fi

else

echo 'Interface could not go down';

fi

Comment: Edit your question, your comment it is unreadable !

Comment: @Praveen If you want help you're going to have to add details to your question.  You're putting the details in the wrong place.  Append your details [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/81679/edit).  If you will do what Matsk is asking you to do, you'll get good input and quick resolutions to your issue.